# How to use rsub with Sublime Text with OpenSSH Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, openssh, sublime-text-3

I am using Windows 10 `openssh` (built into cmd) with rsub (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458814/how-to-open-remote-files-in-sublime-text-3) installed on an Ubuntu (18.04 LTS) server and Sublime Text 3. I am connecting using:

```
ssh -p 22 -R 52698:localhost:52698 -i privateKey  user@hostname
```

I am using the command:

```
sudo rsub test.txt
```

it will not return any error or open the file in Sublime Text.

I have checked netstat server side and client side and confirmed that there are TCP services listening on port 52698 client and server side.

Are there any prerequisites that I may be missing?
Are there any firewalls that should be changed server side or client side?

Answer (score 0):

Install [rmate](https://github.com/aurora/rmate) on your Ubuntu machine and use 'sudo rmate file.txt' to open sublimetext locally with rsub installed.

Answer (score 0):

stumble upon the same issue, fixed with `-R 52698:127.0.0.1:52698`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).